# Expected an identifier and instead saw 'else'

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```
if(userThree === "Yes");
{
console.log("You go to your car and realize you've left it unlocked.);
}
else;
{
console.log("You continue to eat your meal.");
}
```

I put this onto JS Bin, but it continues to say:
Expected an identifier and instead saw 'else'.
Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.

I don't know how to fix this

Comment: remove the semicolon after "if", "else", and add quotes after "unlocked."

Comment: 1) Semicolons, 2) Unbalanced quotes. This should be voted as to narrow

Comment: @BlackMaggie actually, Too Localized. (I voted to close, if you don't have 3000 reputation you can flag to close instead)

Comment: No need to downvote this. The meaning of the error message is not clear, and misplacing semicolons is an easy mistake for someone not too familiar with the language. At least OP included both relevant code and the error message.

Answer (score 2):

In your first console.log, your string isn't fully quoted:

```
"You go to your car and realize you've left it unlocked." // <- string needs to end with a quotation mark
```

Also, having semicolons in these (see below) positions won't give you your desired result.

```
if(userThree === "Yes"); <-

else; <-
```

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a closing doublequote in the line below:

```
console.log("You go to your car and realize you've left it unlocked.);
//                                               Here--------------^
```

You also need to remove semicolons after `if` and `else`.

Comment: Thanks. The end quote wasn't missing I just typed something random so my teacher doesn't think I'm plagiarizing. I didn't realize the semicolons after if/else